# Split on grovvy split the sentense into letters instead of words

Tags: groovy, split, soapui

**Split on groovy split the sentence into letters instead of words** 
I work in SoapUI:

There is saved property as string joined with  ',' : 111,222,333 in step-script before.

In next step-script I want to split (with split()) for array.

Instead word-array [111,222,333] i get char array  [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3].

Someone know what reason ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify separator for `split`, like:

```
String input = '111,222,333'
input.split(',') == ['111', '222', '333']
```